# When a Flutter view is embedded into an Android app, how to build in release mode?

Tags: android, flutter, release-mode

One can add a Flutter view to an Android app using the instructions here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

When I build the APK, is the Flutter view in debug mode or release mode? I think it's in debug mode because I see the debug banner (top right corner). How do I switch to release mode?

I'm asking because I see that a bunch of frames are being skipped, and am wondering if these frames are being skipped in release mode too. I'm running on an actual device, not an emulator.

Comment: Did you not find: https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the link. It is/was unclear whether those steps would be for a 100%  Flutter app or for a regular Android app with a Flutter view. E.g. is there a way to just have the Flutter view component be in release mode?

Comment: Just attempting a Debug/Release might be easier than working out the build modes: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter's-modes

Comment: did you find a solution for this case?